# why BOOLEAN of winapi uses 1 for true and 2 for false?

Tags: winapi, types, boolean

I didn't know. just saw it in my debug window a `BOOLEAN` from `STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR` was  resolving to `2` instead of of 1. I got panicked thinking 2 means false. then I realized its 1 for true. But why this kind of odd design ? Or I am doing something wrong in my side ? never heard of anything like multibyte boolean. (BTW I am using MinGW and Qt Creator IDE's Debugger)

Comment: There's a fairly widely used concept of a tribool or triple-state boolean (`true`, `false`, `undefined`). This isn't what's happening here though (or at least, I doubt it), but thought I'd mention it as a response to your last statement.

Comment: Yea, I would like to call that a Trillian, but it seems not to catch on.

Comment: How meaningful `undefined` is for an atomic non-pointer type like Boolean ?

Comment: I've needed it often enough, for instance to indicate that a value is not set yet, or that it should inherit from a parent. But that's beyond scope of the question.

Comment: The data in the struct is only as good as the code that put it there.

Comment: the api uses any non zero number to represent true despite TRUE being defined as 1. 0 is still false

Comment: 0 is false, anything else is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are historical reasons for why many types of boolean exist which is discussed [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx). Essentially any non-zero values are true, and zero is false. This means you shouldn't do comparisons like so:

```
if( x == TRUE )
```

But instead:

```
if( x )
```